# Why is this ListView CheckBox bound to the whole viewmodel and not the row item?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have this `ListView`:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:PersonPickListViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
....
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleOptions}" IsEnabled="{Binding ListEnabled}" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox DataContext="{Binding ElementName=PersPickList, Path=DataContext}" IsChecked="{Binding AllSelected}" Command="{Binding ToggleSelectAll}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=PersPickList, Path=DataContext}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GivenName}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The `DataContext` for the header template checkbox is specifically, and I had assumed locally, set to the entire viewmodel, `PersonPickListViewModel`, because `AllSelected` is a property on that modal, not on a list item object, i.e. a member of `PeopleOptions`, i.e. a `PickListPerson`.

Being that `PickListPerson.IsSelected` is bound inside a cell template, I would guess it would assume the data context of its row, not of its header. When I type "Path" after `Binding`, I get a list of all `PersonPickListViewModel` properties, and not the desired `PickListPerson` properties.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it, please?

Comment: @lukbl I fail to see any similarity. To start with, he is trying to bind one element to another, which is nowhere near my intention. My problem is to get the row checkbox to bind to the `IsSelected` property in each row, to that if I check it, the correct row has its `IsSelected` set to `true. I can't find a binding expression that allows to to bind to "this row's item". It can now bind to any of the whole viewmodel's properties, but not to databound row item's properties.

Comment: you are right about that, I've misunderstood your question.Do you get any error by specifying Binding in this way or is it only the problem with intellisense? what is the type of PeopleOptions? For me with similar xaml it works as expected.

Comment: `PeopleOptions` is of `ObservablleCollection<SelectablePerson>` where `IsSelected` is a property on `SelectablePerson`. 

I don't see any errors in the output window, but ReSharper red-squiggles `IsSlected` in the binding, and if I try another property there, I get a list of properties for my whole `DataContext`, which is `PersonPickListViewModel`

Comment: But does it work at runtime? The fact it shows some error in designer\xaml view does not mean there is really an error. Also, you have to specify DataType of your DataTemplate explicitly (<DataTemplate DataType="YourRowType">)

Comment: Always try debugging your app first before asking for why the strange behavior of the designer. Everything should work just fine at runtime even when the designer complains about ***many things*** by underlining many lines which are supposed to have something wrong. I don't trust in the designer at all because I've experienced many things weird with it, it helps you much but don't expect it to provide all what you want, it's just a tool, maybe the most buggy tool created by Microsoft (of course it may be improved in future), however its buggy *features* are acceptable =))

Answer (score 2):

I believe your question is void because you're operating on a wrong assumption that the `CheckBox` in question is not bound to the row item, when in fact **it is**. I think you are mislead by the *XAML designer* suggesting members of the main view-model rather than the item view-model when defining the binding. The designer is not a perfect tool, and it only tries to guess what the data context will be at runtime, but it quite often gets it wrong - like in your case.

If I'm not mistaken, it assumes data context will be inherited as it stems from the *XAML* structure:

```
CheckBox ← GridViewColumn ← GridView ← ListView ← ... ← Window
```

But at runtime, the `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate` data template is used as `ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate`, and the `ContentPresenter.Content` is the row item. That `ContentPresenter` is a child of `GridViewRowPresenter` and it represents a cell. So at runtime the templated data is in fact your item view-model.

Answer (score 0):

Did you not forget to set `x:Name="PersPickList"` on the ListView? I cannot find it by name amongst the controls. With setting `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=PersPickList, Path=DataContext}"` you specify that every other binding on the checkbox should find its source in the datacontext of the specified PersPickList control. If that does not find the element in the VisualTree it can cause problems.

Ideally, GridView headers inherit datacontext from the parent control but the cells inherit datacontext from the Row. I managed to make your code working by setting the x:Name on the ListView and to allow IsSelected, AllSelected properties notifying the view via the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Not populating changes with INotifyPropertyChanged can break it as well. But otherwise, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do like this

```
<DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding PersPickList.AllSelected}" Command="{Binding PersPickList.ToggleSelectAll}"  CommandParameter="{Binding PersPickList}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Again, you should post **all** your view model code, because it would be **much** easier to determine what's goin wrong.

Comment: I don't only want to select all, in fact, I didn't say the problem was with the header and I don't believe the model code makes any difference. The question is 100% about XAML code, I asked about "`PickListPerson.IsSelected` that is bound inside a cell template`". The binding you describe, sans command, is in in my header template and works fine. You should read the question **carefully**, because it makes it easier to **understand**.